# Connect to aws storage gateway with s3 backing from a different cloud vps (say digitalocean)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-storage-gateway

My goal is to have a s3 backed storage gateway available as a disk on a digitalocean droplet. By watching the video's about storage gateway (e.g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QaCfOatTIDA&t=136s) it seems like it is possible

But I am quite confused by the options available when I go about configuring aws storage gateway. I dont understand which of these options I should choose

[image]

Is there any guide available on how to make aws cloud storage available for a VPS on a different cloud provider?

My digitalocean droplet is an Ubuntu 20.04 if that matters

Comment: Won't regual `fuse` be enough? That's how you can "minimic" mounting S3 on your linux.

Comment: just learned what `fuse` is,  thank you `s3fs` for the win !!

Comment: No problem. I provided an answer with some links to fuse and s3fs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would use [fuse](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fuse.html) to "mount" S3 in your linux OS. Most notably, this can be easily done using  [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse):

> s3fs allows Linux and macOS to **mount an S3 bucket via FUSE**. s3fs preserves the native object format for files, allowing use of other tools like AWS CLI.